# Strange regex issue using findall() and search()

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, search, findall

I'm trying to use **\w{2}\d/\d{1,2}(/\d{1,2})?** in order to match the following two interfaces on a Cisco switch:

Gi1/0/1

Fa0/1

1. When I use re.search(), it returns the desired output.

   ```
   import re
   port = "Gi1/0/1 Fa0/1"
   search = re.search(r'\w{2}\d/\d{1,2}(/\d{1,2})?', port)
   print search.group()
   ```

I get **"Gi1/0/1"** as the output.

2. When I use re.findall()

   ```
   import re
   port = "Gi1/0/1 Fa0/1"
   search = re.findall(r'\w{2}\d/\d{1,2}(/\d{1,2})?', port)
   print search
   ```

I get **"['/1', '']"** which is undesired.

Why does't findall() return  **['Gi1/0/1','Fa0/1']**?

Is that because I used **(/\d{1,2})?**, and findall() is supposed to return this part? Why is that?

How do we get **['Gi1/0/1','Fa0/1']** using findall()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents) docs

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
>   groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
>   group.

In you regex you have a capturing group `(/\d{1,2})?`

You could make it a non capturing group instead `(?:/\d{1,2})?`

Your regex would look like:

[`\w{2}\d/\d{1,2}(?:/\d{1,2})?`](https://regex101.com/r/C7zcLf/1)

```
import re
port = "Gi1/0/1 Fa0/1"
search = re.findall(r'\w{2}\d/\d{1,2}(?:/\d{1,2})?', port)
print search
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/CCAOX96862)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that trick to make it non capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

`search.group()` returns entire match found by the regex `\w{2}\d/\d{1,2}(/\d{1,2})?`. It **doesn't** consider capturing group. It is equivalent to `search.group(0)`. While using `search.group(1)`, it will return `/1`: the result of first capturing group.

On other hand, `re.findall` returns all result of matched groups. To get the expected result, your regex should be

```
(\w{2}\d/(?:\d{1,2}/)?\d{1,2})
```

*Python Code*

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\w{2}\d/(?:\d{1,2}/)?\d{1,2})', port)
['Gi1/0/1', 'Fa0/1']
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
( #Start Capturing group
  \w{2}\d/  #Match two characters in [A-Za-z0-9_] followed by a digit and slash
  (?:\d{1,2}/)? #Followed by two digits which are optional
  \d{1,2} #Followed by two digits
) #End capturing group
```

**P.S.** From your question, I think you are matching only alphabets. In that case use, `[A-Za-z]` instead of `\w`

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response and I learned something new, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it the regex way; this will work:

```
search = re.findall(r'\w{2}\d/\d{1}(?:/\d{1})?', port)
```

You may do this too:

```
>>> "Gi1/0/1 Fa0/1".split(' ')
['Gi1/0/1', 'Fa0/1']
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  
The interface name will vary depends on the model of the Cisco switch, some models are Gigabitethernet, some are FastEthernet. I have another larger script to capture these interfaces on different switches.  Here I just provided a sample code to understand the difference between search() and findall().

Comment: Oh okay. I understand.